# Images don't align on <li>

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to get this images on the same line but the images bump.
This is the code:

HTML

```
  <div class="first-list">
    <ul>
      <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://trendwatching.com/freepublications/?utm_campaign=2016%20Global%20Consumer%20Trend%20Events&utm_content=Footer-FP&utm_source=email" target="_blank">
        <img src="#" />TW:FREE
       </a>
     </li>
      <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://spotters.trendwatching.com/?utm_campaign=2016%20Global%20Consumer%20Trend%20Events&utm_content=Footer-TW%3AIN&utm_source=email" target="_blank">
        <img src="#" />TW:IN
        <a/>
      </li>
      <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://trendwatching.com/about/" target="_blank">
        <img src="#" />TW:ABOUT
      </a>
    </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am following this sample but my images don't align with the li vertically.
http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/kg8HG/

Comment: my code
https://jsfiddle.net/1bhqutss/

Comment: This is an output, not the code, can you attach the code to your question?

Comment: @YagoLoko as a new SO member please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The thing is if I want to have 3 lists with images from left to right,so:
<li><image><text>   <li><image><text>   <li><image><text>
<li><image><text>   <li><image><text>   <li><image><text>
<li><image><text>   <li><image><text>   <li><image><text>

What is the best way?
Thanks

Comment: @YagoLoko Check your fiddle [here] (https://jsfiddle.net/1bhqutss/2/). Is that the way you want it?

Comment: Hi this is how I have it now but i wanted  all aligned.Images don't get vertically aligned like i wanted.
http://postimg.org/image/qls718m71/  (my layout)
http://postimg.org/image/wfzf9o79z/    (how i want to)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is what i got into it.How can i align the images with the text please?
http://postimg.org/image/lulnw3wa9/

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the images on one line, use css property `display: inline`, it will align your items in single line

Answer (score 0):

I got you solution, added float=left in li elements, just increase width in css in case they are not fitting:

```
<div class="first-list">
<ul>
  <li style="float:left;list-style-type: none;">
  <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://trendwatching.com/freepublications/?utm_campaign=2016%20Global%20Consumer%20Trend%20Events&utm_content=Footer-FP&utm_source=email" target="_blank">
    <img src="#" />TW:FREE
   </a>
 </li>
  <li style="float:left;list-style-type: none;">
  <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://spotters.trendwatching.com/?utm_campaign=2016%20Global%20Consumer%20Trend%20Events&utm_content=Footer-TW%3AIN&utm_source=email" target="_blank">
    <img src="#" />TW:IN
    </a>
  </li>
  <li style="float:left;list-style-type: none;"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://trendwatching.com/about" target="_blank">
    <img src="#" />TW:ABOUT
  </a>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<style>
div{
width:1080px;
}
</style>
```